# Explicitly mark a conversion as destructive

Tags: word-choice

If I convert some eggs, milk and flour into pancakes, then I have destroyed, or at least modified, those ingredients.  But if I convert a distance from miles to kilometers then I destroy nothing.

Is there we brief, elegant way to make explicit that destruction is involved?

Athough I am interested in this as a point of English, I want to use the result in choosing names in a computer program.  The routine

```
create_pancakes_from(ingredients, recipe)
```

uses up the ingredients but leaves the recipe alone.  How do I make this distinction explicit but non-horrible?   How would I do that in an English sentence?

Comment: One could say that you *use* the eggs, etc., to make the pancakes. You don't *use* the miles to make the kilometers; you *express* the distance in terms of one or the other.

Comment: And I wouldn't, in fact, say that I *convert* eggs into pancakes. I make pancakes from the eggs; and again I don't make kilometers from the miles.

Comment: As a programmer myself, I would suggest "make_pancakes" as the name of the routine.  Make implies the combining and "destroying" as you put it in a way that Create does not.

Comment: "Make" also has the connotation of building something  out of pre-existing materials, whereas Creating suggests building something where there was nothing. So unless you are frying divine pancakes, say "make" ;]

Comment: mkpancake(ingredients, recipe)

Comment: Anyone who claims that pancakes are in any way, shape, or form destructive is morally, ethically, and empirically sorely mistaken and must be lynched and/or exorcised at once. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **consume**:

In pseudo code

```
new pancake pk;
pk.employ(recipe);
pk.consume(ingredients);
```

Alternatives to employ (that don't give any impression of destroying): apply, utilize, implement

Alternatives to consume (that leave no doubt the object is destroyed): devour, expend

Answer (score 0):

I think the verb "convert" here isn't going to help; the best way to "mark it as destructive" is to use a different verb. I agree with the commentators "convert eggs and milk into pancakes" sounds an odd thing to say, it is understandable but not idiomatic.

Some options:

> Turn eggs and milk into pancakes
>
> Make pancakes out of eggs and milk
>
> Transform eggs and milk into pancakes
>
> Metamorphize eggs and milk into pancakes

HTH.

Comment: I think "make" is the only real option here. *None* of the others sound natural, unless you're being sarcastic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is an interesting one.

From the English language perspective, I'd say that "spend" is the verb you want. That describes the act of losing one thing to gain another.

*"I spent the eggs and milk on pancakes"* might not be a common turn of phrase, but in context it would make sense. Consider it as a response to the question, *"What happened to the eggs and milk?"*

That's not an awesome word to use in your particular case though, because what you've asked for isn't exactly that, is it?

```
spend_on_pancake(milk, eggs)
```

...*might* make sense, but

```
spend_on_pancake(ingredients, recipe)
```

...would imply that recipe would also be spent, which seems wrong.

The imperative nature of a function name here also means that you probably actually want:

```
purchase_pancake(milk, eggs)
```

Which again wouldn't work with the recipe argument.

Having said all that... none of this is idiomatic programing language. Which isn't to say that you shouldn't try to forge something new here, just that you'd be going out on a limb. May I ask what you're conceptually trying to achieve here? Are you intending to destroy the contents of the ingredients array in the function?

Answer (score 0):

The term often used among programmers is '**immutability**'.  Immutable objects cannot be changed after being created.  **Mutable** objects can be changed.  So if your 'recipe' is an object, you'd develop it's public interface such that there are no methods or functions that can be called which modify it's internal state (after it is initialized).  If instead of an object you have a primitive type, like an integer, you can often times mark it such that it cannot be changed.  For example, C# has the **readonly** keyword which protects it from being changed after initialization.

So if you want to express to others (or your future self) that objects shouldn't change, the best thing to do is to design them to be immutable so they cannot be changed.  If this is not an option (perhaps you don't own the source for the 'recipe' type), then consider documenting your functions to describe exactly what they do, versus trying to condense it all down into a function name.

Answer (score -1):

We can answer the question in two ways, in terms of programming languages and in terms of natural language.

PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE : "Passed by Reference"
The OP has two parameters being passed to the `make_pancakes` function: `ingredients` and `recipe`.  The `recipe` is read; the `ingredients` are combined thereby losing their individuality.

The `ingredients` parameter is *passed by reference*, so that the function changes the values visible in the outer scope, i.e. in the program that invoked it.

NATURAL LANGUAGE : "altered/unaltered"
The `recipe` parameter is read and remains unaltered.  The values passed in the `ingredients` parameter (whether it's an array or a custom object) are altered by the function.

Comment: That's not right at all. The act of passing by reference doesn't mean that the function intends to modify the object. Instead in only indicates that the object will not be copied to the function. Mutability, and or the intent to mutate are not implied. Some languages have specific constructs for that, i.e. GLSL allows one to mark an argument as "in", "out" or "inout", while C++ allows the use of the "const" modifier to indicate that an argument will specifically not be mutated.

Comment: If the argument is passed by reference, there is certainly the *possibility* that it can be altered within the scope of the invoked function. And there's more than the possibility--otherwise why pass by reference in the first place (apart from attempts to limit memory consumption)?  Also, functions have no intentionality. In the API developer is where the intentionality resides.

Comment: No, programing languages can very much encode intent. The keywords I mentioned are absolutely intended as declarations of intent. The 'const' keyword is so much so a declaration in nature that it can be ignored in the implementation by using a const cast. It's a language feature that almost entirely exists now as a means for one programer to communicate intent to another. As for references, in C++ almost all parameters bar simple value types are commonly passed by reference to avoid the copy. In Java and Javascript, the *only* option for an object is to pass a reference to it!

Comment: A language gives the developer some ability to express intent (if that's what you mean by "encode intent"). Even better, the developer can include natural language comments in the code and make the intention clear. As we know, what the program does is not always what was intended.